# Unknown error: call function result missing 'value' Appium Hybrid App

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, selenium-chromedriver

I have ussue when Sending Keys to some field

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login-main\"]/a")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/ion-nav-view/ion-view/login-popup/ion-pane/ion-content/div/form/label[2]/input")).sendKeys("Example");
```

I set the context to " driver.context("WEBVIEW_********"); "  , and I can click buttons in the app , but cant put keys into fields , and it happens for 1st time , last week it was working . 
The error is :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
(Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.109)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 
(e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

I try to update the chromeDriver with " npm install -g chromedriver " in the CMD , but the chromeDriver didnt update to 2.36 which is the latest version.
I looked up in another questions , and they have same issue , but I think the problem is that I cant update the chromeDriver

Comment: Seeing the same issue here as well. Saw this on Friday.

In addition, this or something similar also seems to stop us using the debugger in chrome to debug the content of our hybrid app as well.

Comment: Seems upgrading chromedriver doesn't seem to help either. Just managed to get mine to upgrade to 2.36 using npm install -g chromedriver, but still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution how to fix the issue with updating the chrome driver to 2.36 
It was to download the chromedriver version and to find out where is the "version of chromedriver" that is taken by Appium 
the path was

```
C:\Users\Rosen\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\chromedriver\win\chromedriver.exe
```

and change it with the new version , so it fix the problem and stop telling me that there is an issue .

Answer (score 2):

The error says it all :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value
(Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.109) 
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *chromedriver=2.33*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.33*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v60-62**

- You are using *chrome=65.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.36*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.36/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v65-66**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is unknown to us.
- Your *JDK version* is unknown to us.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver* version (*v2.33*) and the *Chrome Browser* version (*v65.0*)

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u162**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u162-relnotes-4021436.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.11.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  [**ChromeDriver v2.36**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v65.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.36 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.36/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Chrome* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of Chrome.
- Execute your `@Test`.

---

### Update :

As per your comment if you are unable to upgrade to *ChromeDriver v2.36* you can adopt either of the following strategies :

- Keep **chromedriver=2.33** but downgrade to **Chrome v60-62**
- Upgrade **chromedriver=2.34** and downgrade to **Chrome v61-63**
- Upgrade **chromedriver=2.35** and downgrade to **Chrome v62-64**

Comment: Well i cant upg the ChromeDriver to v2.36 in Appium , or at least it dont say its upg to 2.36 ... JDK is up to date , but if I want to use the debugger in Chrome  I must have the latest version

Comment: I think I manage to update the chromeDriver according to CMD 
"ChromeDriver 2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91) "
but when I run the code :
 (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.109)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120
Even if I change the Chrome version at the PC , it doesnt changed in the Appium information after the crash , Not change on chromeDriver or GoogleChrome driver

Comment: same thing I ran into. I am not sure why appium decided to package an older version of chromedriver.

Answer (score 0):

So, not sure what route you use to manage your driver, but you need to pass the --chromedriver-executable parameter to your appium run. I'm assuming a new appium version or appium-chromdriver npm package will be released at some point, but until then, try the following:

If you start appium via the command line this is as simple as running:
`appium --chromedriver-executable=/path/to/chromedriver.exe`
(pointing at a 2.36 chromedriver executable)

If you start appium using an AppiumServiceBuilder instance, you need to add:
`serviceBuilderInstance..withArgument((ServerArgument) () -> "--chromedriver-executable", chromeExecutablePath);`

Hope this helps, it seems to be working for me!

Comment: Well I use appium-desktop-setup-1.4.0 . I use " http://www.automationtestinghub.com/appium-tutorial/ "  To install Appium and make the settings , and it was working fine till last week .  I update the chromeDriver , as the system in CMD told me that its 2.36 but when I run the code it keep saying taht its 2.33