# Unable to scroll chrome browser using Appium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, selenium-chromedriver, appium-android

I am trying to scrolldown chrome browser for my appium project but I am unable to scroll down. Below is the error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.109)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
```

There is a mismatch between ChromDriver and ChromeBroser version may be. How to check my ChromeDriver verison (2.33 as present in the error log) in my android device. How can I update the current version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unknown error: call function result missing 'value' Appium Hybrid App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49252945/unknown-error-call-function-result-missing-value-appium-hybrid-app)

Answer (score 0):

Update both chrome browser and chrome driver to latest version.Recent version of chrome browser doesn't work until driver is updated to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution how to fix the issue with updating the chrome driver to 2.36 It was to download the chromedriver version and replace it with the "chromedriver" that is taken by Appium the path was

```
C:\Users\Hamza_Soltani\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\chromedriver\win\chromedriver.exe
```