# Error while click on elements in mobile browser

Tags: selenium, appium

I have initiated Remotewebdriver for initiating driver in mobile device using HPE Mobile center with appium. It was working fine before. Once the chrome driver is updated the mobile browser elements cannot be clicked.

the code for initiating mobile browser.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("userName", ReadProperties.Properties("MobileUsername"));
capabilities.setCapability("password", ReadProperties.Properties("MobilePassword"));
capabilities.setCapability("udid", ReadProperties.Properties("MobileUID"));
capabilities.setCapability("browserName", ReadProperties.Properties("MobileBrowser"));
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", ReadProperties.Properties("MobilePlatform"));
log.Info(capabilities.getVersion());
mobile_driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(""+ReadProperties.Properties("MobileURL")+"/wd/hub"),capabilities);
```

Once executed the logs:

> 2018-04-06 11:41:45,528 ERROR t.C.Log [main] ||
>   NoSuchElementException: The Object ICA Gruppen Home> Language label
>   not found! unknown error: call function result missing 'value'

```
(Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.109)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:15.31Z'
System info: host: 'SEV000268', ip: '10.59.66.86', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_162'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {bootstrapPort: 28741, browserName: chrome, databaseEnabled: false, desired: {bootstrapPort: 28741, browserName: chrome, deviceName: ZX1G428PXX, newCommandTimeout: 300, noReset: true, password: ******, platform: ANY, platformName: ANDROID, systemPort: 28741, udid: ZX1G428PXX, userName: *******, version: }, deviceName: ZX1G428PXX, deviceUDID: ZX1G428PXX, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: true, newCommandTimeout: 300, noReset: true, password: Infosys777, platform: ANY, platformName: ANY, platformVersion: 7.1.1, systemPort: 28741, takesScreenshot: true, udid: ZX1G428PXX, userName: achu.s.pillai@ica.se, version: , warnings: {}, webStorageEnabled: false}
Session ID: 10882ea8-4cbe-4b77-ac6a-5355020abf96 ||
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unknown error: call function result missing 'value' Appium Hybrid App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49252945/unknown-error-call-function-result-missing-value-appium-hybrid-app)

Comment: I have tried the using chromedriver 2.37 version, but even the **(Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)** is displayed. Is there any location from where the default chromedriver is fetched. Thanks

Comment: See RosS answer below in that discussion. That may help you.

Comment: I have gone through the solution, but i am using java-client for appium which doesn't need appium installed on PC.I am using HPE Mobile center for device connection. In such case from where does the chromedriver gets triggered.